# Script about disk space

Tags: linux, scripting

i would like to make automatic a function to see when disk space is over 90%....
I know how to use df, but i don´t know how to put it as a script. I would like some help here !

Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean by "put it as a script?" How to program the >90% calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Write your script that checks space, then put it in [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crontab).

Cron allows you to run commands at a specific time interval, and is exactly what you need to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`:

```
df | grep -v 'Use%' | awk '{if($5 > 50) print $1 " uses " $5 " of its total space"}'
```

Sample output:

```
[adrian@cheops3:~]> df | grep -v 'Use%' | awk '{if($5 > 50) print $1 " uses " $5 " of its total space"}'
/dev/md2 uses 73% of its total space
/dev/sdb4 uses 66% of its total space
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
_servers="user1@server1 user2@server2 user3@server12"
_out="/tmp/output.$$"
_email="you@example.com"
_sub="Disk Space Report $(date)"
_ssh=/usr/bin/ssh
_mail=/usr/bin/mail

>$_out
for s in $_servers
do
    $_ssh $s df -H >>$_out
done

$_mail -s "${_sub}" $_email <$_out
```

Run this from one of your servers which can login to rest of all servers using ssh keys without password. Setup a cron and you are done. If you want output for all server otherwise you can apply for 1 server also.